# Deleting a single line in an axes in MATLAB GUIDE

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, line, axes

everyone. I have been looking for a solution to this problem for a while now. I have created a MATLAB GUI using GUIDE. To simplify the program, I have just 2 components: axes2 which is an axes and a checkbox to plot something on the previously mentioned axes2.

When the checkbox is checked, it would plot a line. When it is unchecked it would delete that plotted line. Sounds simple even for a newbie like me.

However this is the problem I encounter:

```
if get(hObject, 'Value') == 1
    axes(handles.axes2);
    x = handles.x;
    distanceX_Plot = evalin('base', 'somesignalfromtheworkspace');
    hold on;
    distanceX_Plotted = plot(x,distanceX_Plot, 'r', 'Parent', handles.axes2);
    hold off;
else 
    delete(distanceX_Plotted);
end
```

This is the code I have written which does not work. I get the error:

> Undefined function or variable 'distanceX_Plotted'.

I checked the existance with exist('distanceX_Plotted'). distanceX_Plotted exists only in the if statement. When the program leaves that statement exist functions returns 0.

I have used findobj to learn if the line itself exists and it returns the line as Line in the list created after calling findobj. However, I do not know how to manipulate Line object, how to reach it or delete it. If your answer will be using this method please try to tell it like I am a very dumb person.

Things I have tried:

1. Deleting handles.axes2 in the else statement which works put is useless as I want other checkboxes to plot other things at that axes which would stay.
2. Creating a handle for the distanceX_Plotted in the IF and deleting it in ELSE which did not work at all.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: You provided the code that creates the varoable 'distanceX_Plotted', but not the code that results in the error. My guess is, that the error is generated outside of the scope of the variable and can therefore not find it. So, check where the rror is thrown and make sure that at that point you have access to the variable.

Comment: That line in the code is the first instance of distanceX_plotted. Howeveri I have found the solution myself. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

so if you want to access `distanceX_Plotted` variable, you need to store it somewhere after creation. Otherwise, scope of the variable is the `if else` cycle and the variable does not exist outside of it. You can store it in the figure's handle object. For example if your figure variable is called `MyFigure` you can do this:

```
MyFigure.UserData.distanceX_Plotted = plot(x,distanceX_Plot, 'r', 'Parent', handles.axes2);
```

and then when you need to delete it

```
delete(MyFigure.UserData.distanceX_Plotted);
```

otherwise, you can use `findobj`

```
obj = findobj('Properties','Values');
delete(obj);
```

Comment: Yes, but I tried to delete the variable in the scope of the if else cycle. Your answer probably would work too but I do not get it it is literally just below the else... Thanks anyway, I have found a solution too, do you think it will work?

Comment: your variable was defined when if statement would return true. But deletion would take place only when the if statement would return false. So it is two different scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution:

```
function checkbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
x = handles.x;
distanceX_Plot = evalin('base', 'CAN2_MPC_C19_Dist_X_VehObj0_Cval_MPC');
distanceX_Plotted = plot(x,distanceX_Plot, 'r', 'Parent', handles.axes2);
if get(hObject, 'Value') == 0
    delete(distanceX_Plotted);
end
```

The checkbox callback function will do whatever you write inside when it is clicked so my first if statement in the question code is not actually needed. Using the if for deleting the line, it worked.

Comment: this solution might have problems in the future if you will want to add other objects to your figure. The problem here is that when you delete the line you don't delete already existing line, but you draw a new line (regardless of the state of the checkbox) and then delete this new line. If you will want to use `hold on` in the future on these axis you might face some problems I think.

Comment: That is exactly the error I got right now. You are totatlly right. It is great that you saw that coming. Thank you very much.